# Html string to google doc format file in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I have a string `str` containing html and I want to save it in an opened google doc format file in a way like this: `doc.getBody().appendParagraph(str);`
How can I convert that string in a doc format?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the html to save in a rendered state in the doc?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK there is no function that would only get the text presented in the web page. But using the XML Service can be used to [parse](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html) HTML and it can be a bit cumbersome to navigate through the DOM tree but I think this is the only way to write html string (rendered) to a doc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can I save the html string in a html file and then (with some google file api) convert the whole html file in a doc file?

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me

```
function html_to_doc() 
{ 
 var html = '<html><body><h1><i><b>HEADING</b></i></h1></body></html>';
 var mediaData = Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(html, "UTF-8").setContentType("text/html");
 var resource = {
     title: "Html_to_doc",
 };
 var optionalArgs = {
     convert: true
 };
 var newFileId = Drive.Files.insert(resource, mediaData, optionalArgs);
}
```